# symmetric_difference Output as Two Separate Lists

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, symmetric-difference

Let's say we have two lists of values, whereby each list only contains unique values unto itself. There will never be duplicate values in a single list.

```
L1 | L2
-------
a  |  a
b  |  d
c  |  e
d  |  g
e  |  h
f  |  i
   |  j
```

We can get the differences of these lists using `set(L1).symmetric_difference(L2)`, but unfortunately that lumps the results together in a single list. For example, the output of `list(set(L1).symmetric_difference(L2))` is `['c', 'b', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'f', 'g']`.

Is there a way to obtain two separate lists of output from `list(set(L1).symmetric_difference(L2))` like `['c', 'b', 'f',]` and `['h', 'i', 'j', 'g']` instead?

Or is there a way to obtain two separate lists as output while comparing the two sets/lists against each other only once?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following:

```
dif_1_from_2 = list(set(L1) - set(L2))
dif_2_from_1  = list(set(L2) - set(L1))
```

And you can create a function to do that like this:

```
def get_symmetric_difference(L1, L2):
    return list(set(L1)-set(L2)), list(set(L2)-set(L1))
```

and then you call it like this:

```
print(get_symmetric_difference(L1, L2))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, thx, but is there no way to get the two lists of output while comparing the sets only once??

Comment: Is my updated answer gives you what you asked in your comment? Please let me know.

Comment: no, unfortunately that's not what i meant. what i'm trying to get at it is that `dif_1_from_2` compares the sets once, then `dif_2_from_1` compares the sets for a 2nd time. is there no way to compare `L1` and `L2` once, but get two different lists as the output? does that make sense?

Comment: Not sure, actually. I believe you would really need two operations to do that at the end.